# How to rename a local grid filter of type list

Tags: extjs, filter, grid

In 'MyGrid' for column Col1, I changed the values coming from store True or False to Yes (for True) and No (for false). If I don't specify any options under filter, the filter list appears as True, False. I want to do local filtering with Yes (For True) and No (for False). How can I acheive this?

```
Ext.define('TestGrid', {
      requires: [
        'Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature'
      ],
      extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

      initComponent: function() {
        var myStore = Ext.create('MyStore');

        this.columns = [ 
          {
            text: 'Col1',
            dataIndex: 'Col1',
            sortable: true,
            draggable: false,        
             renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
              //changing from true/false to yes/no
               if (value) {
                 return 'Yes';
             } else {
             return 'No;
             }
             }                    
          }          
        ];

        this.features = [
          {
            ftype: 'filters',
            local: true,
            encode: false,
            filters: [

                      {
                        type: 'list',
                        dataIndex: 'Col1',
                        options: ['Yes', 'No'],
                        phpMode: true                                     
                      }
                      ]
          }          
        ];    
        this.callParent(arguments);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even easier (wonder why I didn't try it before)

```
 {
                    type: 'list',
                    dataIndex: 'Col1',
                    options: [
                          [true,'Yes'],
                          [false, 'No']                            
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Got a solution!

```
validateRecord: function(record) {
var valArray = this.getValue(), rec = record.get(this.dataIndex), i, re, retval = false, changedValues = [];

                              //for each values in valArray add appropriate value in changedVal //for Yes -> True and No -> False                      
                              for(i in changedValues) {
                                re = new RegExp(changedValues[i], 'gi');
                                if(re.test(rec)) {
                                  retval = true;
                                }
                              }
                              return retval;
                            }
```